# GDAL polygonize in python creating blank polygon?

Tags: python, gdal

I am having trouble using the Polygonize function in python.  The cookbook example for this can be found [here](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html).

The relevant portion of my code is:

```
sourceRaster = gdal.Open('myraster.tif')
band = sourceRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
bandArray = band.ReadAsArray()
outShapefile = "polygonized"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
if os.path.exists(outShapefile+".shp"):
    driver.DeleteDataSource(outShapefile+".shp")
outDatasource = driver.CreateDataSource(outShapefile+ ".shp")
outLayer = outDatasource.CreateLayer("polygonized", srs=None)
gdal.Polygonize( band, None, outLayer, -1, [], callback=None )
outDatasource.Destroy()
sourceRaster = None
```

I know that the band has relevant information, here is a snippet of `bandArray`:

```
array([[ 4.,  4.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,
         3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,  4.,
         4.,  4.,  4.,  4.],
```

When I open the attribute table in QGIS, it is empty:
[image: QGIS screencapture]

**Edit:**

The conversion works just fine in QGIS using Raster -> Conversion -> Polygonize tool

Screenshot of raster to be polygonized:

[image: raster to polygonize]

And screenshot of resultant conversion from QGIS tool:

[image: polygonized raster from QGIS tool]

I am using the Enthought distro on Windows 7, GDAL version 1.10.0-3

**The problem is that I cannot polygonize a raster in python using GDAL and the cookbook example, I can polygonize this same raster with no problem in the QGIS GUI**

Comment: What does your raster look like? Does it really contain polygons? Does it work if you use gdal_polygonize.py instead?

Comment: Edited to add screenshots of working process in QGIS

Comment: What's the actual problem here?

Comment: Added specific problem

Comment: What was the result of using gdal_polygonize.py?

Comment: I had a similar problem (blank shapefile being created), and creating the field didn't help. What I was doing wrong was that I hadn't closed the shapefile in my code before calling polygonize. You do close it in your example, I am just posting this for others' reference.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that I was not creating a field to store the raster band.  After digging through the gdal_polygonize.py file, I realized this is not automatically done when calling gdal.Polygonize, which instead uses the function found [here](http://www.gdal.org/gdal__alg_8h.html#a3f522a9035d3512b5d414fb4752671b1).

Here is the extra step needed to create a field and write a band to the field:

```
newField = ogr.FieldDefn('MYFLD', ogr.OFTInteger)
outLayer.CreateField(newField)
```

We can then write the band to this field, with an index of 0:

```
gdal.Polygonize(band, None, outLayer, 0, [], callback=None )
```

Comment: I am also trying to use gdal.Polygonize() function to get my raster as polygon in python. But at the end line it is showing runtime error!!  why?

Comment: It works well with georeferenced raster files. The result is too many polygons, but i only want one big polygon showing the outline of raster. Does anyone have any idea how it works at the same time?

Comment: Still i'm getting empty shapefile, but i have rows in dbf file. Please clearify me!

Comment: I just had this problem but instead of adding a dummy field, you can enter an index of -1. See [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/trunk/gdal/alg/polygonize.cpp#L385) that field is only added if index >=0.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I fixed by closing the shapefile after using poligonize ("dst_ds.Destroy())":

```
def polygon_response(raster, poligonized_shp):
src_ds = gdal.Open(raster)
if src_ds is None:
    print('Unable to open %s' % src_filename)
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(3)
except RuntimeError as e:
    # for example, try GetRasterBand(10)
    print('Band ( %i ) not found' % band_num)
    print(e)
    sys.exit(1)

#  create output datasource
dst_layername = poligonized_shp
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource( dst_layername + ".shp" )
dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs = None )

gdal.Polygonize( srcband, None, dst_layer, -1, [], callback=None )
dst_ds.Destroy()

polygon_response(raster, poligonized_shp)
```

Comment: this worked for me, thanks a lot!

Comment: this just saved me. Thanks