# ASC to JSON conversion. Where are the attributes?

Tags: raster, geojson, vector

I am converting MetOffice Nimrod `.dat` files to `GeoJSON` via the `asc` format.

The MetOffice `dat` format data is a proprietary type and I am using a script found [here](https://github.com/decvalts/nimrod-toolbox) that converts from `dat` to `asc`.

Using QGIS I can see a reasonable looking output from this `asc` file.

[image]

From the `dat` file I use `gdal` to convert to `json`. I also do some geospatial clipping and convert to the `epsg:4326` projection. I am confident from testing other files that these sections are correct.

I iterate over the `asc` files and use `gdal`, as is show below.

```
for file in glob.glob("*.asc"):
        print("Converting file " + file + " to json")
        src_ds = gdal.Open(file)
        if src_ds.RasterCount !=1:
            print "Raster issue - more than one band detected"
            sys.exit(1)
        if src_ds is None:
            print 'Unable to open %s' % src_filename
            sys.exit(1)
        try:
            srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
        except RuntimeError, e:
            print 'Band ( %i ) not found' % band_num
            print e
            sys.exit(1)
        dst_layername = file[:-4]
        drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("GeoJSON")
        dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource( dst_layername + ".json" )
        dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs = None )
        gdal.Polygonize( srcband, None, dst_layer, -1, [], callback=None )
```

This outputs a reasonable looking GeoJSON file, as shown below. I am happy that this is geospatially correct.

However, my issue lies in the attributes for each of these polygons. The MetOffice NIMROD data contains precipitation measurements.

If I open the `json` file in a text editor, I see the following:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -0.1872638449, 51.653290137600003 ], [ -0.1728164805, 51.653066222 ], [ -0.1735389107, 51.635092885699997 ], [ -0.1879805698, 51.635316657899999 ], [ -0.1872638449, 51.653290137600003 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -0.1735389107, 51.635092885699997 ], [ -0.1590974392, 51.634867338200003 ], [ -0.1594612233, 51.625880718799998 ], [ -0.1738998445, 51.626106194099997 ], [ -0.1735389107, 51.635092885699997 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -0.1594612233, 51.625880718799998 ], [ -0.1450227909, 51.625653468899998 ], [ -0.1453892349, 51.616666906500001 ], [ -0.1598248185, 51.616894083799998 ], [ -0.1594612233, 51.625880718799998 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 0.1687182185, 51.539341131199997 ], [ 0.1831263429, 51.53907385 ], [ 0.1826964281, 51.5300889699 ], [ 0.168291136, 51.530356165599997 ], [ 0.1687182185, 51.539341131199997 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -0.4960296, 51.2999988 ], [ -0.4960296, 51.6806202 ], [ 0.275826, 51.6806202 ], [ 0.275826, 51.2999988 ], [ -0.4960296, 51.2999988 ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

There is no property or attribute metric here which gives a number to the precipitation for this polygon.

Where am I going wrong? Is there a further `gdal` argument for bringing the file attributes across from the `asc` file too?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is you need to explicitly add a field to your output layer to store the rainfall value for each raster pixel when it gets converted to a polygon. Using your script, I added an extra two lines just before the last line:

```
import glob
import sys
import gdal
import osgeo.ogr

for file in glob.glob("*.asc"):
        print("Converting file " + file + " to json")
        src_ds = gdal.Open(file)
        if src_ds.RasterCount != 1:
            print "Raster issue - more than one band detected"
            sys.exit(1)
        if src_ds is None:
            print 'Unable to open %s' % file
            sys.exit(1)
        try:
            srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
        except RuntimeError, e:
            print 'Band ( %i ) not found' % srcband
            print e
            sys.exit(1)
        dst_layername = file[:-4]
        drv = osgeo.ogr.GetDriverByName("GeoJSON")
        dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource(dst_layername + ".json")
        dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs=None)

        precipField = osgeo.ogr.FieldDefn('PRECIP', osgeo.ogr.OFTInteger)
        dst_layer.CreateField(precipField)

        gdal.Polygonize(srcband, None, dst_layer, 0, [], callback=None)
```

Then in my JSON file I get:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "PRECIP": 12 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 126500.0, 699500.0 ], [ 126500.0, 698500.0 ], [ 131500.0, 698500.0 ], [ 131500.0, 699500.0 ], [ 126500.0, 699500.0 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "PRECIP": 27 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 131500.0, 699500.0 ], [ 131500.0, 698500.0 ], [ 136500.0, 698500.0 ], [ 136500.0, 699500.0 ], [ 131500.0, 699500.0 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "PRECIP": 8 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 136500.0, 699500.0 ], [ 136500.0, 698500.0 ], [ 141500.0, 698500.0 ], [ 141500.0, 699500.0 ], [ 136500.0, 699500.0 ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "PRECIP": 3 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 161500.0, 699500.0 ], [ 161500.0, 698500.0 ], [ 166500.0, 698500.0 ], [ 166500.0, 699500.0 ], [ 161500.0, 699500.0 ] ] ] } },
```

...

This answer here helped me: [gdal polygonize in python error, blank polygon created](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92176/gdal-polygonize-in-python-error-blank-polygon-created)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [GeoJSON](http://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html) is a vector format and [asc](http://gdal.org/1.11/frmt_various.html#AAIGrid) is a raster format. You could try exporting to a commonly used (and smaller) raster format like [GeoTif](http://gdal.org/1.11/frmt_gtiff.html).

Comment: Thanks @iant. Do you mean that it is not possible to bring the attributes across from raster to vector?

Comment: I mean that converting from a raster format to a vector format almost never makes sense.

Comment: I see. In my case I wish to attribute precipitation data to some polylines. Consider a road (polyline) passing through one of the 1km square pieces of data (the raster data here). I want to pass the precipitation data from the raster file as an attribute to a vector polyline. Does this make sense?