# Raster to vector conversion using GDAL Python?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, vector, ogr

I have used the following code and it gives me the output shapefile which is of like 4.36 MB but when I open it in QGIS to view the shapefile it shows nothing:

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr
import sys
import os


gdal.UseExceptions()
os.chdir("D:/Nikka")
fileName = "D:/subset_raster.tif"
src_ds = gdal.Open(fileName)
if src_ds is None:
    print('Unable to open %s' % src_fileName)
    sys.exit(1)
srcband = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
dst_layername = "PolyFtr"
drv = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
dst_ds = drv.CreateDataSource(dst_layername + ".shp")
dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs = None)
newField = ogr.FieldDefn('Area', ogr.OFTInteger)
dst_layer.CreateField(newField)
gdal.Polygonize(srcband, None, dst_layer, 0, [], 
callback=None )
```

for reference [GDAL polygonize in python creating blank polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92176/gdal-polygonize-in-python-error-blank-polygon-created/)

Comment: Why don't you think that this is a duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92176/gdal-polygonize-in-python-creating-blank-polygon

Comment: I think you need to delete your dst_ds, dst_layer and to be sure srcband variables after your created your raster with `dst_layer = None`

Comment: you think i should delete the dst_ds and dst_layer then what will i give as parameter in gdal.Polygonize where ive given dst_layer?

Comment: after keeping dst_layer = none i get the following error dst_layer.CreateField(newField)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateField'

Comment: no I mean after you finished your calculations which are shown in your code snippet, you set the variables to None with `dst_layer = None`and  `dst_ds = None`

Answer (score 3):

When you are creating your vector data set to store the output of `gdal.Polygonize()` you are not assigning it a coordinate system.  The spatial reference of your output vector needs to line up with the spatial reference of the raster you are polygonizing.  This is easily fixed by copying the spatial reference from the raster to the vector:

```
from osgeo import osr
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromWkt(src_ds.GetProjection())
```

Now when creating the layer, do:

```
dst_layer = dst_ds.CreateLayer(dst_layername, srs = srs)
```

Now your vector and raster will line up properly.